# Outlook VSTO form does not display in release version (installed)

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Thanks for looking.

I am working on an Outlook plugin that includes a pop-up `Form` that loads a `browser` inside of it to allow the user to log in via a 3rd party auth service.

This works great when running from a debug session: I see the custom tab in the ribbon, click the "login" button, and the form pops up as a modal using .ShowDialog().

I am using Outlook 2016.

## Problem

When I publish this VSTO and then install it on my machine, the plugin loads and I can see the "login" button in the custom ribbon tab, but clicking it does nothing. I have checked to be sure that the dialog isn't simply popping under the main form. If it's there--I can't find it.

Back to debug session--everything works great. I suspect a permissions issue, but I don't get any prompts or errors from Outlook.

Last, I don't know if it's related, but I sent the VSTO installer to a colleague and they get the following error when attempting to install:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this
> application will not work because the certificate used to sign the
> deployment manifest for {APP NAME REMOVED} or its location is not
> trusted. Contact your administrator for further assistance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: While Eugene's answer is correct, I have discovered the root cause of the problem to be unrelated. I case it helps someone else: the pop-up that was loading depended on a URL that was retrieved from a configuration (XML) file. This XML file was not available in the release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your form is shown behind the Outlook window. You need to specify the parent window handle if you want to see the form all the time on top of Outlook windows. The `Show` and [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) methods of the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class allows to specify the parent window handle by passing an instance of the [IWin32Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface as a parameter.

First, you need a class which implements that interface:

```
public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
   public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
   {
       _hwnd = handle;
   }

   public IntPtr Handle
   {
       get 
       { 
          return _hwnd; 
       }
   }

   private IntPtr _hwnd;
}
```

In Outlook you can cast an instance of the `Explorer` or `Inspector` class to the `IOleWindow` interface and get the window handle which can be used for the `IWin32Window` implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much Eugene, I have added this class, but am having a little trouble implementing the last part. Would you be so kind as to provide an example of getting a reference to the parent window? Also, my dialog is being launched from a separate thread--I am assuming that this could also be the cause, what do you think? Apologies--I have inherited a distressed project and I am not a VSTO or Windows Forms developer. Thanks again for your help.